# Clarification needed on (u/i)int_fastN_t

Tags: c, memory, c99, unsigned, signed

i read many explanation on fastest minimum-width integer types but i couldn't understand when to use these data types.

My understanding :
On 32-bit machine,

uint_least16_t could be typedef to an unsigned short.

```
 1. uint_least16_t small = 38;
 2. unsigned short will be of 16 bits so the value 38 will be stored using 16 bits. And this will take up 16 bits of memory.
 3. The range for this data type will be 0 to (2^N)-1 , here N=16.
```

uint_fast16_t could be typedef to an unsigned int.

```
 1. uint_fast16_t  fast = 38; 
 2. unsigned int will be of 32 bits so the value 38 will be stored using 32 bits. And this will take up 32 bits of memory.
 3. what will be the range for this data type ?
    uint_fast16_t => uint_fastN_t , here N = 16
    but the value can be stored in 32 bits so IS it 0 to (2^16)-1 OR 0 to (2^32)-1 ?
    how can we make sure that its not overflowing ? 
    Since its a 32 bit, Can we assign >65535 to it ?

    If it is a signed integer, how signedness is maintained.
    For example int_fast16_t = 32768;
    since the value falls within the signed int range, it'll be a positive value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `uint_fast16_t` is just the fastest unsigned data type that has at least 16 bits.  On some machines it will be 16 bits and on others it could be more.  If you use it, you should be careful because arithmetic operations that give results above 0xFFFF could have different results on different machines.

On some machines, yes, you will be able to store numbers larger than 0xFFFF in it, but you should not rely on that being true in your design because on other machines it won't be possible.

Generally the `uint_fast16_t` type will either be an alias for `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, or `uint64_t`, and you should make sure the behavior of your code doesn't depend on which type is used.

I would say you should only use `uint_fast16_t` if you need to write code that is both fast and cross-platform.  Most people should stick to `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, and `uint64_t` so that there are fewer potential issues to worry about when porting code to another platform.

### An example

Here is an example of how you might get into trouble:

```
bool bad_foo(uint_fast16_t a, uint_fast16_t b)
{
    uint_fast16_t sum = a + b;
    return sum > 0x8000;
}
```

If you call the function above with `a` as 0x8000 and `b` as 0x8000, then on some machines the `sum` will be 0 and on others it will be 0x10000, so the function could return true or false.  Now, if you can prove that `a` and `b` will never sum to a number larger than 0xFFFF, or if you can prove that the result of `bad_foo` is ignored in those cases, then this code would be OK.

A safer implementation of the same code, which (I think) should behave the same way on all machines, would be:

```
bool good_foo(uint_fast16_t a, uint_fast16_t b)
{
    uint_fast16_t sum = a + b;
    return (sum & 0xFFFF) > 0x8000;
}
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, but I would suggest `return (sum > 0x8000) || (sum < a);` to portably test for test for `sum > 0x8000`.  `(sum & 0xFFFF) > 0x8000;` fails for `a=0xFFFF, b=1`.

Comment: @David but someone on this site mentioned that Fixed width integer types are optional in C.

Comment: @David Is it because of working with types of machine word size would be more efficient. Is it like saying " Let the expression be evaluate at a faster rate, we'll take care of the result " ?

Comment: @Harsha, if your compiler supports C99 then you I think you can include `stdint.h` and get access to fixed-width types like uint16_t.  Why did you say they were optional?  Did you have a question about it?  Is there something about my answer that is wrong?

Comment: @Harsa, to your second comment, I would say the answer is yes.  On a 32-bit processor, it might be faster to store a 16-bit integer in a 32-bit register and let the programmer (instead of the compiler) worry about when exactly the upper bits need to be masked off.  That's what `uint_fast16_t` allows us to do.

Comment: @Harsha please let me know if my answer doesn't fully explain what you needed to know.  If it does, please click the checkmark on the left to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @DavidGrayson If your machine doesn't have native integers of size N, the types intN_t and uintN_t don't have to exist. That is the reason to have int_leastN_t and uint_leastN_t, which need to exist for N=8, 16, 32 and I'm not sure if 64 too.